# Phrases for (someone) making a short visit/appearance

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

> - When I need to visit to any place for a very short time, say, for  10-15 minutes
> - A politician coming late and leaving in minutes at a fundraiser.
> - An acquaintance just dropping by to say Hello.
> - A supporting actor

Phrases such as  "drop by," "drop in," "come over, etc. come to mind"

What kind of phrases do we associate with such a short filmsy appearances.

Is there a single word?

Comment: You can say he made a *cameo appearance* (most typically applied in your "supporting actor" scenario).

Comment: Oh!, I was missing that "cameo" word, else I would have written, "a supporting actor in a cameo role". Many Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A few choices-
>
> - **stop by** for a few moments.
> - **[drop round](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/drop-round)** for a few minutes
> - **[pop in](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pop+in)** 
>     for a minute

I like the expression - an **abbreviated** **visit**-  though I have  not heard of this phrase before and could not find much  [reference](http://www.eurasianet.org/departments/insight/articles/eav102407a.shtml).

> And for the supporting cast- **Cameo**- the suggestion by *Dan Bron*
>   definitely appears the most suitable.
>
> - If you are fond of cricket, you would hear of "[**cameos**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cricket_terms)" by batsmen, which is a brief but quick-scoring innings.

Comment: +1 This is my favorite answer.  I have a suggestion for one additional bullet point.  As an American English speaker in the Northeast US, I hear the phrase "pop in" used quite often when someone is talking about a short social visit to a person's home.

Answer (score 5):

You're describing [a flying visit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flying+visit), it might also be pro forma or perfunctory, depending on why it is short.

Answer (score 1):

Another couple options:

"**swing by**" or "**swing round**" - These give the impression of just stopping in for a short period of time.

"**look in on**" - Gives the impression of just checking up on someone/something and as soon as the curiosity is satisfied, the querier will be on their way.

HTH.